# Manualy send password reset link in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I was trying to send a password reset link to my newly created user and had a hard time trying to find a solution. In case someone has the same issue here is what worked for me in Laravel 7.

Or is there a better way to handle all: add entry in password_resets table and send the notification?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = auth->user();
$token = app(\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($user);
$user->sendPasswordResetNotification($token);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.